# adding a dynamic cell reference in vba

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am using the following code to insert a formula into a cell using vba. 
The code inserts a hyperlink with some static text leading to a file path and then at the end of my file path I want to be able to add a dynamic cell reference, for instance A and then the number of the row.

In my cell in column A I have the names of folders. I am using DestRow to define the current row number. So my question is how can I correct my formula so that when the link is clicked it opens the link to get the correct folder name of the row clicked? Thanks

```
 ws2.Range("S" & DestRow).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\ATTACHMENTS\"" & K" & DestRow & ",""Attached"")"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
ws2.Range("S" & DestRow).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\ATTACHMENTS\" & ws2.Range("K" & DestRow).Value & """,""Attached"")"
```

FWIW, I hate working with quoted strings as well.

*Addendum:* This should do for adding a static filename after the dynamic folder:

```
ws2.Range("S" & DestRow).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\ATTACHMENTS\" & ws2.Range("K" & DestRow).Value & "\audit.xls"",""Attached"")"
```

Comment: thanks this worked great, do you know how I could then add a static file at the end of this path? (after the dynamic cell reference? i.e. & ""\audit.xls""

Comment: @Henry Fisher - I've amended the post with an example of including a static filename. Thanks for the positive feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You could try including the INDIRECT() function:

```
ws2.Range("S" & DestRow).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\ATTACHMENTS\"" & INDIRECT(""K""&" & DestRow & ",""Attached"")"
```